# Drools + Spring (Is there any coverage plugin or framework for drl file)

Tags: java, spring, drools

Actually we are validating unit test case manually against drl file for coverage of rules. Maintenance is very hard in this scenario. Can any one one help us on this issue.

Comment: Rule events can be registered automatically using the appropriate listener(s).

Comment: Can you help me with the sample. We are looking for coverage of drl file.Expecting result should clearly shows what are all the rules skipped, What are all failed like that.Like Karma coverage in angular js.